# C++ Saving objects inside a list to reuse later

Tags: c++, data-structures

Suppose I own a list of edges saved inside a vector like:

```
typedef struct edge
{
  int v;
  size_t start;
  size_t end;
}e;

typedef vector<list<e>> adj_list;
adj_list tree;
```

I have to do logic on this `tree` object, but the logic is too complicated to do it in place (constricted to not recurse). I need an extra data structure to handle each node. As a simple example, lets consider incrementing each edge's v value:

```
list<e> aux;
  aux.insert(aux.begin(), tree[0].begin(), tree[0].end());
  while (!aux.empty())
    {
      e& now = aux.front();
      aux.pop_front();
      now.v++;
      aux.insert(aux.begin(), tree[now.v].begin(), tree[now.v].end());
      
    }
```

The problem in doing this is that the changes made to the `now` variable does not reflect the value in `tree`. I need a list(can be any list(vector,linked,queue,stack) that has an empty() boolean like Dijkstra) ds to handle my `edge` objects in `tree`. Is there an elegant way to do this? Can I use a list of iterators? I'm specifically asking an "elegant" approach in hopes that it does not involve pointers.

Comment: What is the problem with using pointers? Iterators usually also use references or pointers "under the hood", so the solution is pretty similar (including having to worry about potential invalidation of the stored iterator or a pointer becoming dangling)

Comment: statistically speaking, I have made lots of errors using pointers in the past. The logic I need is also complicated. So, it makes sense to avoid pointers if possible, but resort to them if only no other viable solution is out there.

Comment: Well, you can change `aux` to be of type `list<adj_list::iterator>` and then replace `e& now = aux.front();` with `e& now = *(aux.front());` and that *should* work. But only if you make sure that the iterators stored in `aux` don't get invalidated by modifications of `tree`

Comment: @UnholySheep I'll test it.

Comment: Iterators *are* (slightly generalised) pointers. Almost every reason to avoid pointers is applicable to iterators.

Comment: @UnholySheep It does the trick!, post it as an answer, I'll vote it!

Comment: Some notes: (1) don’t use `typedef struct` in C++. (2) You *almost never* want to use `std::list`, it’s incredibly inefficient, even when your algorithm performs semi-regular inserts. But since your code only inserts and removes from the front, using a vector (and logically inverting it, i.e. reversing back and front) is probably *always* more efficient. (3) What do you mean by “constricted to not recurse”? *Do* use recursion. It looks like it’s the right solution here. Gratuitously avoiding recursion makes code complex, brittle and error-prone.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yep, It is really inefficient as it exceeded my time constraints. But that is fine as this approach was a proof of concept and a naive algorithm for stress testing a much more complicated algorithm. No recursion, for this algorithm is going to exceed 10000 stacks easily. But, thank you for pointing out the `std::list`, I forgot about its constant factors.

Comment: @SilverFlash Fair enough, linear traversal is often not a good fit for recursion, I misinterpreted your description. That said, for completeness I will note that modern C++ compilers perform tail call optimisation reliably, so that tail recursive algorithms *can* handle infinite stack frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the solution is to store iterators instead of copies, e.g.:

```
list<list<e>::iterator> aux;
aux.insert(aux.begin(), tree[0].begin(), tree[0].end());
while (!aux.empty())
{
  e& now = *(aux.front());
  aux.pop_front();
  now.v++;
  aux.insert(aux.begin(), tree[now.v].begin(), tree[now.v].end());    
}
```

This works only if you can guarantee that nothing will invalidate the stored iterators, such as certain operations on `tree` could do.

As pointed out by [n. 'pronouns' m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-pronouns-m), iterators can be considered as "generalized pointers", so many problems that regular pointers have also apply to iterators.

Another (slightly safer) approach would be to store `std::shared_ptr`s in the inner list of `tree` - then you can simply store another `std::shared_ptr` to the same object in `aux` which makes sure that the object cannot be accidentally deleted while it is still being referenced

Comment: Maybe a `std::queue` would be more appropriate here for `aux`?

Comment: Minor note: `list<adj_list::iterator>` needs to be `list<list<e>::iterator>` as we need to store iterators of edges (for the individual lists in my adjacence vector). Not an iterator to my adjacency vector itself.