# G++ tail recursion optimization failing

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I base this question on a comment I got for a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63153203/c-saving-objects-inside-a-list-to-reuse-later). A user replied I can have infinite tail recursion stacks. This is not what I found in practice however. To illustrate my point, take a look at my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void tail_print(string& in, size_t& index) //prints in backwards
{
  if (index == 0)
    {
      cout << '$' << endl;
      return;
    }

  cout << in[index];
  index--;
  tail_print(in, index);
}

int main()
{
  string a("abc$");
  size_t pos = a.length()-1;
  tail_print(a, pos);
  return 0;
}
```

Lets say the input string `in` contains characters in between the range: 1<in.length()<1000000.

The code is compiled with: `g++ -pipe -std=c++14 -O2 $file -lm -o exe`

This throws signal 11 (SIGSEG). I can't precisely tell at which input this fails, but I can tell with some certainty that the cause of this signal is from within this subroutine (works fine if I print the characters backwards with a for loop). Please note that this is part of a larger program so there may be unforeseeable complications (slim chance). In either way, I have to cast some doubt about tail recursion optimization if it causes a *stackoverflow* at a measely O(million) depth.

I'm using the following g++ version:

```
~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~16.04) 5.5.0 20171010
```

Comment: Why zero index is considered as the exit condition? Do you iterate characters in the string from 1 to the string length?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles added main() and includes.  Note that I haven't added the failing input as mentioned above. It is probably machine dependent. I don't have access to the original machine which threw segfault.

Comment: If you take a look at the assembly generated, you will see that the function in your question [is not tail recursive](https://godbolt.org/z/KxP65e).  It looks like `std::endl` flushing `std::cout` is enough to require the compiler to generate extra exception handling code that prevents tail call optimization.  Change `endl` to `'\n'` and you will find that tail call optimization [is applied](https://godbolt.org/z/1GsdT7).  Just another chapter in the parable titled "Never Use `endl` Unless You Know You Really Have To".

Comment: @S.M. As I have stated above. This recursion logic prints string backwards. I could have tested this with a normal print, but I want to preserve the original code in case if it failed because of such logic

Comment: @MilesBudnek nope, it does not seem to be the problem: `"Reconstruct String from Burrows-Wheeler Transform:                                                                    
    Failed case #27/44: unknown signal 11 "`(sigseg)

Comment: Actually you're right, I was misread the assembly.  The `endl` makes it more complicated, but the main part of the work is done iteratively.

Comment: GCC 10 can optimise the tail recursion: https://godbolt.org/z/q6M487 earlier versions don't for some reason. Given tail recursive code can trivially be replaced with a loop why bother taking the risk?

Comment: Looks like it's just the version of your compiler. GCC 9.1 [does not do tail recursion](https://godbolt.org/z/PrMWqn). GCC 10.1 [does](https://godbolt.org/z/xvvYj8). That's C++ for you. There are no guarantees around tail recursion. Just because something looks tail recursive does not mean the compiler will emit tail recursive code.

Comment: thank you for solving this mystery. I indeed confirmed it working on my gcc build at 1 million depth. Post as answer to vote it

Comment: looks like `cout << char` is what prevents the optimisation, strange

Comment: @AlanBirtles it works with g++ 10.1 on my machine. Is there an additional depth limit? (beside failing because of outdated build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rely on tail recursion you are at the mercy of the compiler as to whether it chooses to optimise your code. Debug builds will not be optimised so will always fail.

In your case printing a single character through `std::cout` seems to be the cause of your issue. libstdc++ seems to implement printing a single character via a call to:

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
```

For some reason this seems to trip up the tail recursion optimisation before GCC 10. All versions of Clang fail to optimise this too.

Replacing `cout << in[index]` with `std::cout.put(in[index])` seems to allow all versions of GCC (down to 4.1.2 at least) and Clang to optimise the tail recursion: https://godbolt.org/z/Th1bT8

Interestingly calling `std::__ostream_insert` directly also works (but don't do that as you are then relying on internal libstdc++ implementation details): https://godbolt.org/z/9M5xd4

I think through the various levels of function call in [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d242fdaec1866ddb05b1c36108e51b7d16aa6f79/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ostream#L515) you end up with (due to the function `char` argument being taken by value):

```
char c = in[index];
std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::cout, &c, 1);
```

Creating a pointer to a local variable seems to be what prevents the tail recursion: https://godbolt.org/z/KM4jGY, presumably this is because the compiler can't know what the called function will do with that pointer so it can't guarantee that using a loop will have the same behaviour.

As all tail recursions should be trivially replaceable with a loop its best to not rely on the vagaries of the compiler to do it for you, this will then work even in an unoptimised build:

```
void tail_print(const std::string& in, size_t index) //prints in backwards
{
    for (size_t i = index; i > 0; i--)
    {
        std::cout << in[i];
    }
    std::cout << "$\n";
}
```